# Previous function, but for two (or more) rows previous

Tags: crystal-reports, function

I'd like to get the value of a cell, two rows previous, is that possible?

I know I can do the row previous, but I'd like two (or more) rows previous

```
Previous({myTable.myColumn})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per answer on crystalreportsbook.com

> Crystal is limited to only one record previous and one record after (next).

Answer (score 4):

Not with any standard functionality that I'm aware of.

Off the top of my head, though, you could try shared variables.

For example, you could have `PrevRecord1` and `PrevRecord2` variables.  A function that is in the detail row of the report would then update `PrevRecord2` with `PrevRecord1`, and then update `PrevRecord1` with `Previous({myTable.myColumn})`.

The obvious downside to this solution is you'll need a variable for each row you want to go back.