# Crystal Report and ASP.NET - Make Repeating Values Supressed to One

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using ASP.Net c# in my application. In reporting, Crystal Report is used to produce the Yearly Sales of tenants. In my database (SQL Stored Procedure), The below table representation  is produced.

```
Tenant      Year    Sales
Strarbucks  2010    1000
Strarbucks  2011    2000
Strarbucks  2013    3000
Strarbucks  2014    4000
Strarbucks  2015    5000
```

What I want or desired output in Crystal Report is for the Repeating Tenant Name to be compressed as one like this

```
Tenant      Year    Sales
Strarbucks  2010    1000
            2011    2000
            2013    3000
            2014    4000
            2015    5000
```

What I have done initially is to have a Group by Tenant, But it is resulting to this:

```
Strarbucks  
2010    1000
2011    2000
2013    3000
2014    4000
2015    5000

Tenant 2    
2010    1000
2011    2000
2013    3000
2014    4000
2015    5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare your report as in the first example you have created i.e.

```
Tenant      Year    Sales
Strarbucks  2010    1000
Strarbucks  2011    2000
Strarbucks  2013    3000
Strarbucks  2014    4000
Strarbucks  2015    5000
```

Then `Right Click` on `Tenant` field in the report design.
Click on `Format Field`
On the `Common` tab enable the option at the bottom `Suppress if Duplicated`.

Your report may need to be sorted by `Tenant` field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are putting the "Tenant" in the details group (or in the year group), and is being repeated as many times as you have year.

I would recommend the you create a group with "Tenant" and put the designation there. Then a group with the year, and put the other fields in that group. Once this is done you will have a ladder like report, and you simply go to the "Tenant" group section and choose the "Underlay following sections" option.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy by using previous word.

Check this :

[Formula for Suppressing Field if duplicate in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599476/formula-for-suppressing-field-if-duplicate-in-crystal-reports)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?605984-suppress-if-duplicate-%28group-level%29

[Previous function, but for two (or more) rows previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415444/previous-function-but-for-two-or-more-rows-previous)